# emacs live on windows seeing error opening file

Tags: git, emacs, clojure

Was wondering if anyone else has seen this.

- Using cygwin
- Using git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0
- Using GNU Emacs 24.3.1
- Using emacs-live

After starting up emacs, when attempting to open any file, I am seeing the following error message:

```
call-process-shell-command: Searching for program: permission denied, /bin/bash
Error in post-command-hook (global-git-gutter-mode-check-buffers): (file-error "Searching for program" "permission denied" "/bin/bash")
```

However, the following returns nothing:

```
$ grep -R global-git-gutter-mode-check-buffers .emacs.d/
```

I can't sem to follow why this code is complaining, and why I can't find the post-command-hook it is referring to?

Answer (score 1):

1. The `post-command-hook` function, `global-*`, is probably in some file that you load that is outside your `.emacs.d` directory.
2. You can try bisecting your init file (`~/.emacs`) recursively, to find which part is problematic. That will help you locate `global-*`, though it does not sound like that is the real problem.
3. It sounds like the real problem is that the Cygwin directory `/bin/bash` does not have you as the owner, or you do not have the necessary permissions.

Hopefully someone will be able to help more with the problem, but this might get you started.